# Cannot convert from object to integer Talend

Tags: java, talend

i m using a numeric sequence in Talend

so

```
if (some condition)
{  output_row.Seq =  Numeric.sequence("S2", globalMap.get("i"), 0); }

else {  globalMap.put("i",Numeric.sequence("S1", 1, 1));
        output_row.Seq = globalMap.get("i"); 

 }
```

and I got a fehler, Cannot convert Object to Integer,

I think it is by the  `numeric.sequence ("S2", globalMap.get("i"), 0);`  how to tell to talend that i is an integer please?

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it to an Integer:

```
Numeric.sequence("S2", (Integer)globalMap.get("i"), 0)
```

Comment: it doesn t solved the problem, i finally just change the type of the output_row.Seq field , to make it as an Object, and it works...